# .NET UnitOfWork as a static class - is it good idea ?

Tags: c#, unit-of-work

I read that article http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122 because I want to find an answer how to close/dispose DB context in the `Repository pattern` where we don't need the connection anymore.

I see that `UnitOfWork` is a `static` class and the context is being created within `Application_Start` and disposed within `Application_EndRequest`. The whole concept looks nice, I can manage the connection over whole application.

But, is marking the `UnitOfWork` class as `static` a good idea ? I'm wondering, because in that way the `UnitOfWork` class is being shared over all incoming requests. Wouldn't be better if the `UnitOfWork` class won't be `static` and it could be created/disposed dynamically within `Global.asax` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `UnitOfWork` class in the sample is indeed static, but if you read the code in-depth you will see that `UnitOfWork.Current` is creating or looking up an instance stored in the `HttpContext.Current`. So no, the instance you will be working with is per-request, not shared globally.